# Run sql and plsql queries from a file whenever I call a service in SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, plsql, service

So guys I am working on a spring boot application where whenever saves something in a table (suppose A) I would like to trigger a service that runs SQL/PLSQL scripts (those scripts basically retrieve some values from other tables) and then compare the output of SQL/PLSQL scripts with what user has saved. So is there any way to achieve this?

So assume that table A is updated from another service in another application so is there any way my current application can know it is updated or would I have to manually refresh it?
Secondly, how can I run those scripts either way?Any code example would be very helpful .

Comment: When your "service" compares the output, then what? If it's supposed to fail user commit when something is wrong, that's one answer. If it's supposed to modify the db data in another table, then there's another answer. If it's supposed to call back into the Java from SQL, that's a combination of second problem and DBMS-specific way to run external programs.

Comment: As of now, it is not supposed to fail the commit. It will just display in UI nothing else.

Comment: How can it display anything in UI if updates can come in from another service entirely, which generally means your UI isn't required to be open?

Comment: Actually, the service is exposed to the UI via rest API. So the plan is whenever service gets called it  compares the value of A and value from output of SQL Scripts and after UI can get it via a simple REST API

Comment: Then it's just going to run some SQL code, which is easily searched on here, and you don't even need Spring to do it. Though I'm still confused as to why you included "updates from another application" into your question if your service will just be called from somewhere. What does another application have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the power of the database for this, this would not require any code on your application side. Some options are:

- Create a trigger on your table that execute the pl/sql code
- (if you don't want to run the pl/sql on every update, but only - say - once every hour). Create a trigger on the table that inserts a row in a queue table. Create a job (using API `dbms_scheduler`) that is fired hourly which checks the queue table for records and executes the pl/sql if needed.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I can do that since I have limited access to db . Is there any way to achieve it via Spring Boot?

Comment: I'm a database focused developer... that is up to a spring boot specialist to answer.

Comment: Okay No problem. Thanks